# C - Print to console a string that can be deleted

Tags: c, console

I'm trying to build a program that prints a "default value" an user can quickly change by deleting parts of it and writing again.

The program would print for example:

```
enter app name: xcode
```

The user should be able to replace the "xcode" string (but not the ": " part) and then the program should get the entire input.

Is there a way to do it in plain C with the standard console OSX uses?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think that you can do that with the plain console. You will need a means to place the cursor anywhere in the console. The ncurses lib might be useful here.

Comment: I believe the best way to achieve this behavior would be to print the default value before the prompt (like in the `nano` program). In `nano`, when you search for a string, the default is the previous search and the prompt is like so: `Search for [lastSearch]: ` and blank input yields the default value.

Comment: I like that! And if the user presses return the default value is accepted. Unfortunately I wanted to make it possible to rewrite portions of the string, but I can live with that for the sake of compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will place a prompt and default input on the screen. The arrow keys will move the cursor right and left. Mode may be changed from INS (insert) to OVW
(overwrite) using the Ins key. Enter will terminate input as will too many characters. Valid characters may be restricted by using some combination of LETTERS | NUMBERS | DOT | SPACE | SIGN | PUNCT.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define ESC          27
#define INSERT       50
#define DELETE       51
#define PGUP         53
#define PGDN         54
#define ARROWRIGHT   67
#define ARROWLEFT    68
#define END          70
#define HOME         72
#define OTHER        79
#define BRACKETLEFT  91
#define TILDE       126
#define BACKSPACE   127

#define LETTERS       1
#define NUMBERS       2
#define DOT           4
#define SPACE         8
#define SIGN         16
#define PUNCT        32

#define SIZE         30

static const int STDIN = 0;

typedef struct Field {
    int row;//place input on screen row and col
    int col;
    int contentsize;//allowed length of input
    int inputat;//input at this index
    int used;//characters used so far
    int valid;//limit input to these characters
    int insert;//mode insert/overwrite
    int promptrow;//place prompt on screen row and col
    int promptcol;
    int promptsize;
    int lastline;
    int lastcol;
    int stopon;//stop input with this character
    char *content;
    char *prompt;
} field;

int kbhit(void)
{
    int bytesWaiting;

    ioctl(STDIN, FIONREAD, &bytesWaiting);
    return bytesWaiting;
}

void prompt ( field *psfield) {
    printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->promptrow, psfield->promptcol);
    printf ( "%s", psfield->prompt);
}

int input ( field *psfield) {
    int ch = 0;
    int to = 0;

    printf ( "\033[%d;1H", psfield->lastline);
    if ( psfield->insert) {
        printf ( "INS");
    }
    else {
        printf ( "OVW");
    }

    printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col);
    printf ( "\033[K");//erase to end of line
    printf ( "%s", psfield->content);
    printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col + psfield->inputat);

    while ( ( ch = getchar ()) != psfield->stopon) {
        printf ( "\033[%d;10H", psfield->lastline);
        printf ( "\033[K");//erase to end of line
        printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col + psfield->inputat);
        if (
           ( ( psfield->valid & LETTERS && isalpha ( ch)))
        || ( ( psfield->valid & SPACE   && ch == ' '))
        || ( ( psfield->valid & DOT     && ch == '.'))
        || ( ( psfield->valid & SIGN    && ( ch == '+' || ch == '-')))
        || ( ( psfield->valid & NUMBERS && isdigit ( ch)))
        || ( ( psfield->valid & PUNCT   && ispunct ( ch)))
        ) {
            if ( psfield->insert && psfield->inputat < psfield->used && psfield->used < psfield->contentsize-3) {
                //expand
                psfield->used++;
                for ( to = psfield->used; to >= psfield->inputat; to--) {
                    psfield->content[to + 1] = psfield->content[to];
                }
                printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col);
                printf ( "\033[K");//erase to end of line
                printf ( "%s", psfield->content);
            }
            printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col + psfield->inputat);
            printf ( "%c", ch);
            psfield->content[psfield->inputat] = ch;
            psfield->inputat++;
            if ( psfield->inputat > psfield->used) {
                psfield->used = psfield->inputat;
            }
            if ( psfield->inputat == psfield->used) {
                psfield->content[psfield->inputat] = '\0';
            }
            if ( psfield->inputat >= psfield->contentsize-1) {
                return -1;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if ( isprint ( ch)) {
            printf ( "\033[%d;10H", psfield->lastline);
            printf ( "\033[48;5;124m");//set color white text on red
            printf ( "Invalid character");
            printf ( "\033[0m");//reset to default colors
            printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col + psfield->inputat);
            continue;
        }
        if ( ch == BACKSPACE) {
            if ( psfield->inputat) {
                psfield->inputat--;
                //contract
                for ( to = psfield->inputat; to <= psfield->used; to++) {
                    psfield->content[to] = psfield->content[to + 1];
                }
                psfield->used--;
                printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col);
                printf ( "\033[K");//erase to end of line
                printf ( "%s", psfield->content);
                printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col + psfield->inputat);
            }
        }
        if ( ch == ESC) {
            if ( !kbhit ( )) {
                continue;
            }
            ch = getchar ( );
            if ( ch == OTHER) {
                ch = getchar ( );
                if ( ch == HOME) {
                    psfield->inputat = 0;
                    printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col);
                    ch = getchar ( );
                }
                if ( ch == END) {
                    psfield->inputat = psfield->used;
                    printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col + psfield->inputat);
                    ch = getchar ( );
                }
            }
            if ( ch == BRACKETLEFT) {
                ch = getchar ( );
                if ( ch == INSERT) {
                    ch = getchar ( );
                    if ( ch == TILDE) {
                        psfield->insert = !psfield->insert;
                        printf ( "\033[%d;1H", psfield->lastline);
                        if ( psfield->insert) {
                            printf ( "INS");
                        }
                        else {
                            printf ( "OVW");
                        }
                        printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col + psfield->inputat);
                    }
                }
                if ( ch == DELETE) {
                    ch = getchar ( );
                    if ( ch == TILDE) {
                        //contract
                        for ( to = psfield->inputat; to <= psfield->used; to++) {
                            psfield->content[to] = psfield->content[to + 1];
                        }
                        psfield->used--;
                        printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col);
                        printf ( "\033[K");//erase to end of line
                        printf ( "%s", psfield->content);
                        printf ( "\033[%d;%dH", psfield->row, psfield->col + psfield->inputat);
                    }
                }
                if ( ch == ARROWRIGHT) {
                    if ( psfield->inputat < psfield->used) {
                        printf ( "\033[C");//cursor right
                        psfield->inputat++;
                    }
                }
                if ( ch == ARROWLEFT) {
                    if ( psfield->inputat) {
                        printf ( "\033[D");//cursor left
                        psfield->inputat--;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                ungetc ( ch, stdin);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main ( ) {
    struct termios oldattr, newattr;
    struct winsize w;
    field sfield = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '\n', NULL, NULL};

    //set terminal
    tcgetattr( STDIN, &oldattr );
    newattr = oldattr;
    newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN, TCSANOW, &newattr );
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    //get terminal dimensions
    ioctl( 0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w );
    sfield.lastline = w.ws_row;
    sfield.lastcol = w.ws_col;

    printf ( "\033[2J");//clear screen
    sfield.row = 5;
    sfield.col = 26;
    sfield.promptrow = 5;
    sfield.promptcol = 1;
    sfield.stopon = '\n';//newline will end input
    sfield.valid = LETTERS | SPACE | DOT;
    sfield.contentsize = 40;//allowed length of input
    if ( ( sfield.content = calloc ( sfield.contentsize, 1)) == NULL) {
        printf ( "calloc failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    sfield.prompt = strdup ( "Enter letters or spaces:");
    sfield.promptsize = strlen ( sfield.prompt) + 1;

    strcpy ( sfield.content, "default");
    sfield.used = strlen ( sfield.content);


    prompt ( &sfield);
    input ( &sfield);

    printf ( "\n\ninput was [%s]\n", sfield.content);
    printf ( "\n\nbye\n");

    free ( sfield.content);
    free ( sfield.prompt);

    //restore terminal
    tcsetattr( STDIN, TCSANOW, &oldattr );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is more complex than I thought. I guess I will stay with the standard input mode or use ncurses if it allows something like that. Thanks for the answer thought!